# Neural network Cost function in Andrew Ng's Lecture

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am having trouble with my code that is meant to provide a cost function for my neural network.  The cost function (J) is defined as the cost function. Given sample inputs, the cost function returns a negative value that is about 5 times less than the expected value. I have worked on this issue for a few hours but still cannot get the desired value.

Thanks in advance.

```
function [J grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
                                   input_layer_size, ...
                                   hidden_layer_size, ...
                                   num_labels, ...
                                   X, y, lambda)
%NNCOSTFUNCTION Implements the neural network cost function for a two layer
%neural network which performs classification
%   [J grad] = NNCOSTFUNCTON(nn_params, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, ...
%   X, y, lambda) computes the cost and gradient of the neural network. The
%   parameters for the neural network are "unrolled" into the vector
%   nn_params and need to be converted back into the weight matrices. 
% 
%   The returned parameter grad should be a "unrolled" vector of the
%   partial derivatives of the neural network.
%

% Reshape nn_params back into the parameters Theta1 and Theta2, the weight matrices
% for our 2 layer neural network
Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
                 hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1))):end), ...
                 num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));

% Setup some useful variables
m = size(X, 1);

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J = 0;
Theta1_grad = zeros(size(Theta1));
Theta2_grad = zeros(size(Theta2));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: You should complete the code by working through the
%               following parts.
%
% Part 1: Feedforward the neural network and return the cost in the

         one=ones(1,10);

         temp=one
         one=transpose(temp);
     sizeTheta1=size(Theta1);
     sizeTheta2=size(Theta2);


for i=1:m

    if y(i)==1
        yVec=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==2
        yVec=[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==3
        yVec=[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==4
        yVec=[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==5
        yVec=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==6
        yVec=[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==7
        yVec=[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==8
        yVec=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0];
    end
    if y(i)==9
        yVec=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0];
    end
    if y(i)==10
        yVec=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1];
    end
    xVec=transpose(X(i,:));


term1=transpose(-yVec).*(log(sigmoid(Theta2(1:10,1:sizeTheta2(2)-1))*(sigmoid(Theta1(1:25,1:sizeTheta1(2)-1)*xVec))));
term2=(one-transpose(yVec)).*(log(one-(sigmoid(Theta2(1:10,1:sizeTheta2(2)-1)*(sigmoid(Theta1(1:25,1:sizeTheta1(2)-1)*xVec))))));

J=J+(term1-term2);
end 

regTheta1=0;
regTheta2=0;

J=sum(sum(J))*(1/m);

regTheta1=(sum(sum(Theta1.*Theta1)));
regTheta2=(sum(sum(Theta2.*Theta2)));

J=J+((lambda)*(regTheta1+regTheta2))/(2*m);

% -------------------------------------------------------------

% =========================================================================

% Unroll gradients
grad = [Theta1_grad(:) ; Theta2_grad(:)];


end
```

Comment: Hey, I am taking this course too and have passed this assignment. Which week was this? I can check where your error is. Also, the way you build `yVec` is not optimal (how would you do if you had 100 possibilities?)
Create a vector of `zeros` and set the `y(i)`-th coefficient equal to 1.

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now, but at first glance it looks like the first term of your cost is wrong.  `log(sigmoid(Theta2(1:10,1:sizeTheta2(2)-1)) * ...`.  Remember that you find the raw scores by taking the neuron response from the input layer and multiplying by the first weight matrix.  You apply the activation, then repeat the same procedure for the second weight matrix.  You've closed off the bracket early, which means that you're only applying the activation function on `Theta2`, not on `Theta2` multiplied by the inputs coming from the hidden layer.  Your second term looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!